# Reindex DataFrame within Dictionary Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary of DataFrames and I am trying to reindex certain dataframes within the dictionary.

```
for key, value in rateDict.items():
    if condition:
        indexRange = list(range(27,46))
        value = value.reindex(index=indexRange)
        print(key,value)
```

This code above returns a dataframe that is reindexed with the `list(range(27,35))` but all of the data within the dataframe is now listed as `NaN`

Comment: When you `reindex` you're essentially saying that you want the rows with those `index` values, if those rows don't exist you get `NaN` so what is your intention here?

Comment: my intention is to completely replace the index with a new one

Comment: then you want `value.index = indexRange`, however, this will only work if the index lengths match

Comment: Issue solved... was a problem with the kernel. THX @EdChum